# Prefixing an Applescript text items list

Tags: applescript, delimiter

I have the following code, which prompts user for a comma separated list of places:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {","}

set thePlaces to the text items of the text returned of (display dialog "Insert referenced places separated by commas" default answer "")
```

This will result on a list with several items ("Paris","London", ...).

My intention is to prefix every item of this list with a string (for eg. "plc:".
In the end, I would like the list to be composed by items such as:

"plc:Paris", "plc:London".

Have been trying but with no luck so far. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks a little brutal, but works as wished:

```
repeat with i from 1 to count thePlaces
    set item i of thePlaces to "plc:" & item i of thePlaces
end repeat
```

The repeat loop loops through the items and add "plc:" in front of the content...

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it with text item delimiters, we box each item, with a unique value for the front, and one for the end, so that we can differentiate between the two. No use for this with so small lists, really. I just wanted to show you how it can be done.

```
set astid to text item delimiters
set the places to "Paris,London,Rome"
set text item delimiters to ","
set lstItms to text items of the places
-- we "box" the text items, so that every one is prepended with a return, and has a linefeed appended to it.
set text item delimiters to return & linefeed
set places to lstItms as text
set text item delimiters to astid
set places to linefeed & places & return
-- our list is in shape, time to do the actual replacement.
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set lstItms to text items of places
set text item delimiters to "plc:"
set places to lstItms as text
set text item delimiters to return
set lstItms to text items of places
set text item delimiters to astid
log item 1 of lstItms
(*plc:Paris*)
```

Comment: Good to know more complex usage scenarios